# Normal table setting

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, tabularx, tabu

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,array,dcolumn,caption,amsmath, textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{charter}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \scriptsize % 30% linear reduction in size
        \captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,font=footnotesize}
        \caption{Add caption}
        \label{tab:addlabel}

        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercol. space
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{10}{d{2.5}r} }
            \toprule
\toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Decisions} \\
\cmidrule{2-10}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Healthcare}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Social}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Consumption} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Financial} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{All} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{9-10} 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\small
\item Source: Authors'   calculations.\\
Standard errors in parentheses \\
{***} p$<$0.01, {**} p$<$0.05, {*} p$<$0.1
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What is your question?

Comment: I am trying to make this table but it's not appear complete. Last columns from 9-10 disappear on the page.

Comment: for `tablenotes` you need to load `threeparttable` .

Comment: your table is to wide.  you should reduce column width somehow, but without knowing content from table body  is difficult to say how to do this. for start reduce font size.

Comment: @RashidJaved The table fits the page for me. You are probably using a paper layout that doesn't fit the table. Maybe [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134574) will help you. Otherwise, please post a MWE that compiles and shows the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

- Your code contains an unfortunate mixture of indicators that the `tabular*` environment should contain either 10 or 20 data columns, for a total of either 11 or 21 columns. In the code below, I provide suggestions for how to fix up your code to make it contain either 11 or 21 columns.
- Loading the `threeparttable` package and using its `tablenotes` environment seems like overkill, especially since you don't appear to use any `\tnote` directives.
- Don't load packages more than once.

Here goes:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,rotating,array,dcolumn,caption,
            amsmath,textcomp,microtype,charter}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip, font=footnotesize}
\scriptsize % 30% linear reduction in size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercol. space

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Possibility 1: 21 columns
\caption{21 columns} \label{tab:21}
%% '*{10}{d{2.5}r}' actually specifies 20, not 10, columns
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{10}{d{2.5}r} }
\toprule %%% please don't ever use double \toprule
Variables & \multicolumn{20}{c}{Decisions} \\
\cmidrule{2-21}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Healthcare}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Social}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Consumption} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Financial} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{All} \\
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{6-9} \cmidrule{10-13} \cmidrule{14-17} \cmidrule{18-21} 
& a & b & c & d 
& a & b & c & d 
& a & b & c & d 
& a & b & c & d 
& a & b & c & d \\
\midrule
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
Source: Author's calculations

Standard errors in parentheses

{***} $p<0.01$; {**} $p<0.05$; {*} $p<0.1$

\vspace{1cm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Possibility 2: 11 columns

\caption{11 columns} \label{tab:11}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{10}{r} }
\toprule %%% please don't ever use double \toprule!
Variables & \multicolumn{10}{c}{Decisions} \\
\cmidrule{2-11}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Healthcare}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Social}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Consumption} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Financial} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{All} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-5} \cmidrule{6-7} \cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{10-11} 
& a & b 
& a & b 
& a & b 
& a & b 
& a & b \\
\midrule
\dots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
Source: Author's calculations

Standard errors in parentheses

$^{***}$ $p<0.01$; $^{**}$ $p<0.05$; $^{*}$ $p<0.1$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```